# Cordova File-Transfer-plugin Download File : Error Code 2

Tags: android, angular, cordova, download, cordova-plugins

I am downloading a file from the server, it returns in Blob format. I have used the following piece of code to convert blob to URL.

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

After that, I have used Cordova-File-Transfer-Plugin code to Download that File. Code provided below:

```
downloadOverMobile(url){
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    let fileURL = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/Invoice.pdf';
    var uri = encodeURI(url);

    fileTransfer.download(uri,fileURL,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("download error code " + error.code);
        },
        false,
        {
            headers: {
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I am getting the following response:

```
download error source blob:file:///d1339351-7d29-4dcd-bba6-0b037003c886
download error target 
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/Invoice.pdf
download error code 2
```

I am using angular 4 and Cordova 8.1.2. Can Anyone tell me what am I missing?